# Devexpress RespositoryLookUpEdit in grid , the value disaper

Tags: devexpress, repositorylookupedit

I have a devexpressgridcontrol. I want to use in one column of the grid : repositoryLookUpEdit.
I fill repositoryLookUpEdit with database question.
 This question return three columns : IdPerson , Name and IdCity. Colums : IdPerson and Name have data but IdCity I have to set in appication.

So 
- in gridcontrol the column Idcity has fildename :  IdCity, and columnEdit : repositoryLookUpEdit.
- repositoryLookUpEdit has DisplayValue : CityName, and ValueMember: IdCity.

And my question is:

When I choose in grid in one row value of city and I go to another row, the value from the first row disaper.

What  am I doing wrong? Could you give me some advise?

I use Devexpress 9.2.

```
this.gvPerson = new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView(); 
this.replueCity = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemLookUpEdit();
this.replueCity.Columns.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfo[] { new     DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfo("IdCity", "IdCity", 20,     DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.None, "", false, DevExpress.Utils.HorzAlignment.Default), new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfo("CityName", "CityName")});
this.replueCity.DisplayMember = "CityName"; 
this.replueCity.Name = "replueCity"; 
this.replueCity.NullText = "[Choose city]"; 
this.replueCity.TextEditStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.TextEditStyles.Standard; 
this.replueOceny.ValueMember = "IdCity"; 
// CityColumn this.CityColumn.AppearanceCell.Options.UseTextOptions = true; 
this.CityColumn.AppearanceCell.TextOptions.HAlignment = DevExpress.Utils.HorzAlignment.Center; 
this.CityColumn.AppearanceCell.TextOptions.VAlignment = DevExpress.Utils.VertAlignment.Center; 
this.CityColumn.Caption = "Ocena"; 
this.CityColumn.ColumnEdit = this.replueCity; 
this.CityColumn.FieldName = "IdCity"; 
this.CityColumn.Name = "IdCityName"; 
this.CityColumn.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Check string "IdCity" in all three cases: it must be written exactly the same (mind the caps!)

Comment: I will check, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Then paste some code...

Comment: Past it to your question, it's not visible in the comments

Comment: I take this code from designer.cs                                this.gvPerson = new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView();                         this.replueCity = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemLookUpEdit();

Comment: // replueCity
            this.replueCity.Buttons.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton[] {
            new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.EditorButton(DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Combo)});
            this.replueCity.Columns.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfo[] {
            new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfo("IdCity", "IdCity", 20, DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.None, "", false, DevExpress.Utils.HorzAlignment.Default),
            new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfo("CityName", "CityName")});

Comment: this.replueCity.DisplayMember = "CityName";
            this.replueCity.Name = "replueCity";
            this.replueCity.NullText = "[Choose city]";
            this.replueCity.TextEditStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.TextEditStyles.Standard;
            this.replueOceny.ValueMember = "IdCity";

Comment: // CityColumn
this.CityColumn.AppearanceCell.Options.UseTextOptions = true;
            this.CityColumn.AppearanceCell.TextOptions.HAlignment = DevExpress.Utils.HorzAlignment.Center;
            this.CityColumn.AppearanceCell.TextOptions.VAlignment = DevExpress.Utils.VertAlignment.Center;
            this.CityColumn.Caption = "Ocena";
            this.CityColumn.ColumnEdit = this.replueCity;
            this.CityColumn.FieldName = "IdCity";
            this.CityColumn.Name = "IdCityName";
            this.CityColumn.Visible = true;

Comment: Make sure that you added the repository item to the GridControl.RepositoryItems collection. The GridControl will activate the editor only in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `ValueMember` for `replueCity` (which is the editor in the column). You set it only for `replueOceny`.

Check string `IdCity` in all three cases: it must be written exactly the same (mind the caps!).

Comment: I set ValueMember only for replueOceny but it still doesn't work. When I choose  value from replookUpEdit in grid, and then I go to next row, the value from first row disappear. yhhh What am I doing wrong!!!!

Comment: Thank you everybody for giving me advise. I solved my problem. Because I filled replueCity from DataTable from DataBase , and also I  filled this grid with another DataTable from the same Database but I used different select. And in grid DataTable wasn't the column which was used to filled replueCity.